# How to read hex values into integer with fstream (C++)

Tags: c++, input, hex, fstream, atoi

I am trying to read a little-endian hex string from a binary file, and put that value into an integer to work with it. When I try to read, instead of getting a number I get ascii symbols. I've tried casts and atoi and nothing seems to work. What is the best way to use fstream to read a hex string into an integer from a file?

This is essentially my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    fstream input;
    fstream output;
    char cbuffer[4];
    char revbuffer[8];

    input.open(argv[1], fstream::binary | fstream::in);
    output.open("output.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    input.seekg(16, input.beg);
    input.read(cbuffer, 4);

    cout << sizeof(revbuffer) << endl;
    cout << cbuffer[0] << cbuffer[1] << cbuffer[2] << cbuffer[3] << endl;
}
```

Comment: is the value really stored as a hex string in the file? You mentioned the byte order and you read 4 chars from the file so a hex string seems improbable.

Comment: Maybe not then, I don't really know how to call it. I'm fairly new to programming. The value is at offset 0x10 and looks something like [in hex] 00 92 f8 03. The number should read 0x03f89200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an integer value stored in binary format, I guess it's either a `int32_t` or a `uint32_t`. Since you mention that the value is stored in little-endian byte order, I guess you want to make sure that the host running your program converts it (if it needs to). C++20 has [std::endian](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian). If that's not available to you, there are usually macros for detecting endianness at compiletime that you can use instead of the `std::endian` tests I've used. I've assumed that the value is a `uint32_t` below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits> // std::endian

// little endian unsigned 32 bit integer to host byte order
inline uint32_t Le32toh(uint32_t le) {
    #if __cplusplus <= 201703L
    // run-time check
    static constexpr uint16_t endian = 1;
    if(*reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&endian)==1) return le;
    #else
    // compile-time check
    static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little || std::endian::native == std::endian::big);
    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) return le;
    #endif

    const uint8_t* c=reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&le);
    return // little-to-big endian conversion
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(c[0])<<24) |
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(c[1])<<16) |
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(c[2])<<8) |
        (static_cast<uint32_t>(c[3]));

    return le;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    std::fstream output("output.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

    uint32_t cbuffer;

    for(const auto& file : args) {
        std::fstream input(file, std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in);
        input.seekg(16, input.beg);
        // read directly into the varibles memory
        input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cbuffer), 4);
        // output the value unconverted
        std::cout << std::hex << cbuffer << "\n";
        // convert if needed
        cbuffer = Le32toh(cbuffer);
        // output the value converted
        std::cout << std::hex << cbuffer << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting an error: 'std::endian' has not been declared. But with main alone I'm now able to read the value as an int. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great! Yes, `std::endian` is a C++20 feature so to be able to do something similar during compile time in C++17 and earlier you'd have to resort to some non-standard endian macro - or do a runtime check. I'll add that too.